# Qt: setting QLabel coordinates inside Widget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel

I'm writing a day schedule and got some troubles: I'm drawing a rectangle on the scheme (rect = event) and I need to put label directly inside of the rectangle. Are there any ways to do that?

P.S. At the moment the scheme is a QWidget and I use QPainter to draw rectangles

Comment: [QWidget::render()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#render-2)?

Comment: For complex views you might consider using QGraphicsView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

knowing the position of the rectangle in QPainter, if you just want to write in it, you can use the QPainter::drawText function.